# Build URL to query JSP

Tags: jsp-tags

Would anybody be able to assist with building a URL to query a JSP db? Basically I'm trying to build a URL containing `<formHeading>` to query `<faglForm>`

When accessing `foo.com/home.jsp` there is a field, which I can pre-populate by accessing the URL as `foo.com/home.jsp?field1=ABCDE`. Then I need to click "submit" to actually access the following page.  I'm looking for a way to "submit" the pre-populated field value as part of the URL.

Comment: Show us what you tried and give detailed feedback on what does not work. If you just write "Can you help me?" that is not enough.

Comment: Sorry Paul, let me be a bit more specific. When accessing http://www.foo.com/home.jsp there is a field, which I can pre-populate by accessing the URL as http://www.foo.com/home.jsp?field1=ABCDE Then I need to click "submit" to actually access the following page. I'm looking for a way to "submit" the pre-populated field value as part of the URL

Comment: I cant understand exactly the issue. Is the home.jsp yours? Show us some code. Where do you need to use this URL with the query string `?field1=ABCDE`? Other JSP? Or Servlet?